# Run applications with bash from Linux Mint

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I started learning Bash on Mint Linux. The thing is I want to know how to open and execute programs. I have a test.sh in my junk directory so that I can mess around but when ever I type in `gnome-open test.sh` it just opens the file and not actually run it. In the test.sh file I have `echo hi` in there so that I can see that it worked and I gave the file the permissions for it to be an executable file so it should execute.

Comment: You can run it with `./test.sh` from your junk directory in a terminal.  For the very basics of bash, try the [bash guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). It gets into how to create and run a script after a bit on running commands interactively.

Comment: From a command line. Try searching for a shell - it might appear under console, terminal etc. in the list of applications from Gnome. After that go to the directory where `test.sh` is located and do what @theotherguy said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Give the file execution permission (+x)
2. Execute the file

First you give the file permission no 755:

```
chmod 755 test.sh
```

Then you start it:

```
./test.sh
```

The dotslash means "*current directory*", it's like saying *c:\file.bat* if \ is the current directory. You need that because the current dir (called *PWD*) is not in your *PATH variable* which means that you either need to specify the complete path, eg. */users/user/file.sh* or using the dot which is a shortcut for the current directory.

The file permission number 755 means:

```
owner: 7 (read, write, exec)
group: 5 (read, exec)
other: 5 (read, exec)
```

If you want to be the only one to be able to even open the file you may specify 700 instead. There are plenty of combinations, but 755 is most commonly used for scripts.

edit:

I forgot to mention that you need the dotslash everytime you run the script, but you only need to issue the chmod command once for every file.

Comment: Thank you so I tell the computer the directory name and the file and it just runs the file without saying to the computer "run this file"? Edit: Not it tells me that /bin is a directory. Me and my linux are both confused

Comment: What's the name of your file and what directory have you put it in?

Comment: Junk/ Also I'm in the Junk/ directory

Comment: Alright, then you issue: _./test.sh_ or _~/Junk/test.sh_

Comment: YYYYEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAH!!!! thank you I just flipped the . and the /